# How to convert special characters in CSV when opened with Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, drupal, unicode, drupal-views, export-to-csv

I have the text with special characters like "Gürhan Bakırküre" but when i export this as CSV and opened with excel it was showing as "GÃ¼rhan BakÄ±rkÃ¼re".

I am exporting the text using drupal data export view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be below link can help you - 
http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2015-05-04/unicode-accented-characters-drupal-views-data-export-and-excel.

In a nutsehll, jus follow below instructions-

Copy views-data-export-csv-header.tpl.php to site's custom theme, and add a single executable line (print "\xEF\xBB\xBF";) to write the BOM:

```
<?php

// Print out header row, if option was selected.
if ($options['header']) {
  // Begin file with UTF-8 BOM.
  print "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
  // Now continue to output header as normal.
  print implode($separator, $header) . "\r\n";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers as links might tend to change or break in the future. Instead explain the answer here itself.

Comment: Thanks user5317514 ..the information in above link helped.

Comment: @prudhvi, I agree with you, i will post the answer seprately, plz vote up

Comment: @user5317514 Please edit your answer, by copying your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the proper *encoding* in the Excel import dialog.  For example, I saved the following sample data into a CSV file:

```
Gürhan Bakırküre, 1
Tim Biegeleisen, 2
```

I saved the file as UTF-8, since I do not know the exact encoding of your actual data.  During the import process in Excel, I made sure to *also* select the same UTF-8 encoding as shown in this screen capture:

[image]

The text rendered in Excel correctly with no problems.  You should probably find out what exact encoding your original file is and use that when you import.

Comment: Thanks Tim, i am exporting the data using  drupal view.May be it causing.

Comment: Please try my answer and then mark it correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 and Drupal 9, Unicode signature can be included in format settings
[image: Format settings > CSV Settings]